# If there are 1000 features files in Cucumber feature file and I want to execute only even feature files. how to do that?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

1000 feature files in src/test/resources.
I want to run only the features file which are even( 2, 4, 6,......1000)
how can we do that?

I tried to group them but not sure like this will be good approach.

Comment: What is "even feature file". "even" implies you have some order. How are your files orderer: by name, by size, by creation date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [JUnit 5 with Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#cucumber-junit-platform-engine) the you can use a [`PostDiscoveryFilter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-post-discovery-filters-custom) from the JUnit Platform to filter out tests.

Something like:

```java
public FilterResult apply(TestDescriptor t) {
   
   // Determine if test descriptor is a feature file based on t.getSource()

   Collection siblings = t.getParent().getChildren();

   // Find index of t in siblings
   // decide to keep or not if index is even


}
```